# How to add additional data label to donut chart

Tags: r, ggpubr

I need help adding a percent data label to the donut chart I've created below.

````r
library(ggpubr)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c("Male", "Female"),
  value = c(38,62))

head(df)
ggdonutchart(df, "value", label = "group")

ggdonutchart(df, "value", label = "group",
             color = "white",fill = "group",
             palette = c("hotpink", "lightblue2") )```
````

Comment: Does [this reference](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggdonutchart.html) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object produced by `ggdonutchart` is a ggplot object, so you can add a `geom_text` with calculated percentages.

```r
library(ggpubr)

ggdonutchart(df, "value", label = "group",
             color = "white",fill = "group",
             palette = c("hotpink", "lightblue2") ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value/sum(value))),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. One last question. Is there a way to get rid of the word group in the legend?

Comment: @freeazabird Sure. Add `+ labs(fill = "")` to the plot

Comment: I've got the plot to almost exactly where I want it with this code.  How can I get rid of the raw numbers, so I just have percent labels?'library(ggpubr)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c("Male", "Female"),
  value = c(38,62))

head(df)
ggdonutchart(df,  label = "group")

ggdonutchart(df, "value",
             color = "white",fill = "group",
             palette = c("hotpink", "lightblue2") ) +
  labs(fill = "") + #THIS DELETS GROUP FROM LEGEND
  
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(value/sum(value))),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))'

Comment: @freeazabird you do only have percent labels. What raw numbers do you have? Remember that 38 and 62 add to 100, so the percentages are the same as the raw numbers. Tru changing `value` to `c(23, 54)` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Here's the graph I get. However, I'd like it to label with % only https://ibb.co/wg4kFnD